# Availability SLA vs Designed for availability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to find out the availability percentage of Amazon's S3. The link is below.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/

What is the difference between Availability SLA and Designed for availability?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to bit confused , let me try to explain in simpler terms from AWS Documentation :

*Availability SLA and Designed for availability?*

The Plain English Translation would be **I can design X service to be available for X Percentage** , that is **just saying that I have designed it** such way!

The **Availability SLA** is you can think of **contract that legally binds them** to serve it so terms defined it it are absolute.

**It is Designed for durability of 99.999999999% of objects.**
- That simply means that the chances of durability of object stored in s3 is that mentioned above.

Now,

**Designed for 99.99% availability over a given year.** 
- Now this is what they say would be s3 as a service you use would be available and **availability of S3 as Service is backed by Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement for availability**.

What is S3 Service Commitment according to [Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement for availability.](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/):

> AWS will use **commercially reasonable efforts** to make **Amazon S3
>   available with the applicable Monthly Uptime Percentage** (as defined
>   below) **during any monthly billing cycle** (the “Service
>   Commitment”). In the event Amazon S3 does not meet the Service
>   Commitment, you will be eligible to receive a Service Credit.
>
> **Definitions**:
>
> - **“Error Rate” means**: (i) the **total number of internal server errors** returned by Amazon S3 as error status `“InternalError” or
>     “ServiceUnavailable”` **divided by** (ii) the t**otal number of
>     requests for the applicable request type during that five minute
>     period**. We will calculate the Error Rate for each Amazon S3 account
>     as a percentage for each five minute period in the monthly billing
>     cycle. The calculation of the number of internal server errors will
>     not include errors that arise directly or indirectly as a result of
>     any of the Amazon S3 SLA Exclusions (as defined below).
> - `“Monthly Uptime Percentage”` is calculated by subtracting from 100% the average of the Error Rates from each five minute period in
>     the monthly billing cycle.
> - A “Service Credit” is a dollar credit, calculated as set forth below, that we may credit back to an eligible Amazon S3 account.
>
> Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: The idea that something is 'designed to support' 'x' but is only 'contractually guaranteed' to be '0.99*x' (or whatever) seems strange.

But outside of that, why talk about what you are not willing to guarantee?

Are you basically saying?

"You will probably experience 99.99% availability, but if you do not get at least 99.9% availability (as guaranteed by our SLA), then we will actually compensate you based on how much we miss the SLA by -- and that chart is over here."